# Flex 4 Use Ellipse as Mask

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

Is there a way within Flex to draw an `<s:Ellipse>` and use it to mask an image? Here is an `<s:Ellipse>` that I have written:

```
<s:Ellipse id="imageFrame" width="150" height="150" rotation="325" top="50" left="50">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:LinearGradientStroke weight="5">
            <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000"/>
            <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"/>
            <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000"/>
        </s:LinearGradientStroke>
    </s:stroke>
</s:Ellipse>
```

... that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to load an image using the `<s:Image>` component, place it inside of the ring, and mask the image so that only the hole in the center is displaying the image, much like a picture frame.

Can that be done, or is that not possible since the "hole" in the center of the ellipse is just invisible fill?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to mask an image by drawing a circle on the graphics of a `SpriteVisualElement` display object.

[image: mask]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               backgroundColor="0x0">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
            {
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

                var g:Graphics = imageMask.graphics;
                g.clear();
                g.beginFill(0xff);
                g.drawEllipse(50, 50, 150, 150);
                g.endFill();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Image id="image"
             mask="{imageMask}"
             source="http://www.artyfactory.com/art_appreciation/art_movements/art%20movements/cubism/still_life_with_mandolin.jpg" />

    <s:SpriteVisualElement id="imageMask" />

    <s:Ellipse id="imageFrame"
               width="150"
               height="150"
               rotation="325"
               top="50"
               left="50">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke weight="5">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Ellipse>

</s:Application>
```